# How image_row_pitch is calculated for image 2d object in opencl while using clenquemapimage()?

Tags: image, opencl

I was working with a simple code (on qualcomm ardreno) which take an gray image of 1024x768 dim and and 100 to each of the pixel element. There might be different ways to create image 2d object and use it but i have used following structs
cl_rgba and cl_unsigned_int16.
I am grouping 4 pixel of 2 byte each and while creating image2d object using clcreateimage() ,i have used width=1024/4.I am mapping this created image object with clEnqueMapImage() with region[3]={1024/4,768,1}.
So when I print the image_row_pitch after this mapping call i get 2112. Which according to my understanding should be (256(width/4)*4(as rgba)*2(size of uint16)=2048). I have also noticed if I use width=960 then i get pitch as 1920 which is expected. I am not able to understand how this image row pitch is coming as a larger value than it should be .
What I am missing here.
kindly help.